# Ender 3 Pro keeps stopping after about 2 or 3 layers. SD card maybe?

Tags: firmware

I bought my Ender 3 Pro 2 weeks ago. Put it together, leveled it, and was off to the races the first day. I printed the test dog and test pig perfectly, so I ventured off to Thingiverse and probably got about 15-20 prints in the last 2 weeks. Everything worked out fine until one morning after a 6-hour print the night before I awoke to a great print and turned my printer off.

When I came back later in the day and turned it back on I was greeted with the blue screen of death!!!! Of course, I panicked and watched a bunch of YouTube videos which led me to "firmware". So I formatted my stock SD card to FAT32 and dropped in the Marlin firmware. The blue screen is gone! Ender dragon back! BUT now my printer will **start** a G-code, but crashes (every time) after about 2 or 3 minutes. BTW, I'm not using Cura or any other cloud slicer. I'm using REALvision and just printing straight from the SD card.

Much easier for me until now, what am I doing wrong? What options do I have other than returning the printer and having to wait for a new one?

Comment: Have you tried another SD card? They can go bad

Comment: Has it ever done this while you were watching it?  Does it restart spontaneously when it fails?